# Possible to have a @NonCPS method read a file in the workspace?

Tags: jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-groovy

I've written a "vars" function in a Jenkins pipeline script that has to read some XML files from the workspace, parse them, construct a string from pieces found in those files, and return a string.

I initially built it without @NonCPS, and it was pretty painful.  I had to null out and reparse the XmlSlurper results several times, including doing that in a loop, as I had to use the "readFile" and "fileExists" pipeline steps.  I did get it working, however.

I realized that if I could make this @NonCPS, this could potentially be simpler, but only if I could get file io to work.

This is the original painful version of the function:

```
def call() {
    def pomFileExists = fileExists "pom.xml"

    if (!pomFileExists) {
        echo "ERROR: No pom file here:"
        sh "ls -lt"
        return ""
    }

    def pomFileContent = readFile("pom.xml")

    def projectPom = new XmlSlurper().parseText(pomFileContent)
    def topArtifactId = projectPom.artifactId.text()
    def topVersion = projectPom.version.text()
    def topJarPath = "target/" + topArtifactId + ".jar"

    projectPom  = null

    def topJarPathExists    = fileExists topJarPath

    List targetJars = []

    if (topJarPathExists) {
        targetJars.add(topJarPath)
    }

    projectPom = new XmlSlurper().parseText(pomFileContent)

    for (int ctr = 0; ctr < projectPom.modules.module.size(); ++ ctr) {
        def moduleDir = projectPom.modules.module[ctr].text()

        projectPom  = null

        def modulePomFileContent = readFile(moduleDir + "/pom.xml")

        def modulePom = new XmlSlurper().parseText(modulePomFileContent)
        def moduleArtifactId = modulePom.artifactId.text()
        def moduleVersion = modulePom.version.text()
        def jarPath = moduleDir + "/target/" + moduleArtifactId + "-" +
                (moduleVersion == "" ? topVersion : moduleVersion) + ".jar"

        modulePom = null

        def jarPathExists = fileExists jarPath
        if (jarPathExists) {
            targetJars.add(jarPath)
        }

        projectPom = new XmlSlurper().parseText(pomFileContent)
    }

    projectPom  = null

    def result = targetJars.join(",")
    targetJars = null

    return result
}
```

Note that some of the objects I nulled out during the process might not have needed to be nulled out.  I sometimes find it hard to tell exactly what objects I need to do that to.

This is my first attempt at a @NonCPS version of this:

```
@NonCPS
def call(workspaceDir) {
    println "workspaceDir[" + workspaceDir + "]"
    def pomFile = new File(workspaceDir + "/" + "pom.xml")
    if (!pomFile.exists()) {
        println "ERROR: No pom.xml file here."
        return ""
    }

    def pom = new XmlSlurper().parse(pomFile)
    def topArtifactId = pom.artifactId.text()
    def topVersion = pom.version.text()
    def topJarPath = workspaceDir + "/target/" + topArtifactId + ".jar"
    List targetJars = []
    if (new File(topJarPath).exists()) {
        targetJars.add(topJarPath)
    }
    for (int ctr = 0; ctr < pom.modules.module.size(); ++ ctr) {
        def moduleDir = pom.modules.module[ctr].text()
        def modulePomFile = new File(workspaceDir + "/" + moduleDir + "/pom.xml")
        def modulePom = new XmlSlurper().parse(modulePomFile)
        def moduleArtifactId = modulePom.artifactId.text()
        def moduleVersion = modulePom.version.text()
        def jarPath = workspaceDir + "/" + moduleDir + "/target/" + moduleArtifactId + "-" +
                (moduleVersion == "" ? topVersion : moduleVersion) + ".jar"
        if (new File(jarPath).exists()) {
            targetJars.add(jarPath)
        }
    }

    return targetJars.join(",")
}
```

Note that the call interface is slightly different.  For this version, I changed the calling code to pass "pwd()".  I also changed the calling code to execute "ls -lt", and it showed the "pom.xml".  I also printed the value of "pwd()", and it was identical to the value of "workspaceDir" that I printed in the method.

The result of this is just "ERROR: No pom.xml file here." and an empty string returned.  That means the File creation didn't work, so it's not able to see the workspace. I verified that this code works in a standalone shell script.

Is it simply not possible to open files in a @NonCPS method?

Comment: Every part of the Pipeline script will always be executed on the Jenkins master. That’s why readFile / writeFile exist. File objects would always try to open files on the Jenkins master file system. For parsing XML I’d recommend using a separate non-pipeline script in the language of your choice which you simply call from the Jenkinsfile.

Comment: Very helpful point about executing on the master. In this case, I think I'm going to stick with the original method I got working, despite the somewhat painful nulling and reloads.

Comment: I don't think it's possible as file reading is a blocking operation and so Jenkins will dump the objects to disk. I think you can read the file and then pass the contents to a @NonCPS function that will do the processing. In your case, you can return a list of candidate files, then check and retain these that exist on disk.