# how to read AssemblyFileversion from assemblyinfo.cs file using groovy script

Tags: jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-groovy, assemblyfileversion

we are trying to fetch the AssemblyFileversion from assemblyinfo.cs file, written code as below and included it in build stage script:

```
def content = readFile(assemblyfile)
def versionPattern = /AssemblyFileVersion\("([^"]+)"\)/
def versionMatch = content =~ versionPattern
def newbuildversion = versionMatch[0][1]
echo "AssemblyFileversion Version: ${newbuildversion}"
```

when we triggered the Jenkins pipeline Assembly file version got printed but the later steps in the build script contains bat file those are not executing.

receiving the error as "PIPELINE FAILED: java.io.NotSerializableException: java.util.regex.Matcher.... Finished: FAILURE"

- tried to run the script in Jenkins Pipeline but receiving the error.
- we are expecting to get Assemblyfile version and run the build script.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to fix NotSerializableException error during Jenkins workflow build?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31654497/how-to-fix-notserializableexception-error-during-jenkins-workflow-build)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Jenkins requires all variables to be serialisable so it can save a pipeline's state at any time and continue it later (or on a different machine).

Generally, if you want to use non-serialisable variables, you need to put that code into a function annotated with `@NonCPS` (more info is available in the docs [here](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/cps-method-mismatches/#common-problems-and-solutions)).

In this case, you can probably get away with just not capturing the variable at all, e.g.:

```
def content = readFile(assemblyfile)
def newbuildversion = (content =~ /AssemblyFileVersion\("([^"]+)"\)/)[0][1]
echo "AssemblyFileversion Version: ${newbuildversion}"
```

Comment: Thank you Simon for response.

Now I am receiving the error as "PIPELINE FAILED: java.nio.file.InvalidPathException: Illegal char < > at index 79: using System.Reflection; using System.Runtime.CompilerServices; using System.Runtime.InteropServices

Comment: That sounds like the path being passed to `readFile` might be invalid (or maybe it's a different piece of file-related code that's throwing) - do you know which line is throwing the exception?

Comment: read file is not working in NonCPS annotation
 
def content = readFile(assemblyfile)

when I moved the readfile out of the NonCPS annotation and kept only version pattern and versionmatch in a function in NonCPS annotation then code worked.

Comment: That seems reasonable, given other questions about `readFile` and `@NonCPS`: https://stackoverflow.com/q/71719060/622391